# Ember Unbound & Belongsto

Tags: ember.js, model, handlebars.js

I have no problem doing {{unbound title}} or

```
{{#each file}}
{{unbound filename}}
{{/each}}
```

on a model.

BUT,
all belongsto object in ember is really problematic for me.
None of ways below work

```
{{unbound location.address}}
```

and

```
{{with location}}
{{unbound address}}
{{/with}}
```

both of these two result in empty output

Answer (score 1):

At the time your model is being processed, any `belongsTo` relationships are not resolved yet. Since you're not binding, it can't retroactively update once that data is available either. I found this workaround yesterday, helping my solve my (similar) issues with `belongsTo`: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1405

> For existing records, you need to do something like the following in
>   your route:

```
// your-route beforeModel: function() {   var self = this;   return
Em.RSVP.hash({
    firstBelongsTo: this.store.find('first-belongs-to'),
    secondBelongsTo: this.store.find('second-belongs-to')
    }).then(function (models) {
      self.controllerFor('this-route').setProperties(models);   });
```

> And in your controller, be sure to declare the properties before
>   setting them as Ember tries to throw then into content when they don't
>   exist:

```
// your-controller App.MyController = Ember.Controller.extend({  
firstBelongsTo: null,   secondBelongsTo: null });
```

> By returning a promise in the beforeModel hook, you are telling the
>   route to resolve the promise BEFORE loading the model, which also mean
>   before any rendering occurs. This gives your application time to load
>   the data up front before binding it to the select boxes.