# Ember-Model: How to establish a hasMany or belongsTo relationship by using a "foreign key"?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-model

### Summary

I have a bit of a problem using Ember-Model, trying to establish a unique relationship between two models.

Based on current responses that I have received here on S.O., [Ember Forums](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/establish-a-hasmany-relationship-using-a-foreign-key/6012), and [#emberjs](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=emberjs).  I am beginning to believe that there is no built-in solution for this problem, and I am reformatting my question to specify what is needed.

### Details

I am populating a template currently with a full set of debtor information.  All the information comes from multiple calls to the server.

The first bit is the basic Debtor info.  This part is easy because I can use the model hook and a dynamic segment to retrieve it.

My server returns a JSON for a Debtor... Here's the short version:

```
{
  "debtor" = {
    "debtor_id": 1003,
    "debtor_name": Steve,
     //... more JSON
    "debtor_contact_id": 1345
  }
}
```

The dynamic segment for Debtor is filled with the value of the `debtor_id`, but also notice this debtor has a `debtor_contact_id`.  Every Debtor record retrieved from the server has a unique `debtor_contact_id`.  On the database, this value is a "foreign key" that will tell which contact table belongs to which debtor table.

There is no way to predict which contact info relates to which debtor without this key/value pair.

I currently have "Contacts" `belongsTo` "Debtor", but that is not enough to do the job.

When it is time to fill the "Contacts" model.  Ember-Model needs to know to build the value from `debtor_contact_id` into the ajax URL *as a query parameter* in order to GET the correct API.

I am still learning all of this stuff and so far I have not been able to fully follow any tutorials because my use case has an extra step needed somewhere.

**This is the expected behavior I am hoping to see:**

1. Model hook will work as expected to pull the specific debtor and put it into a "debtor" model (this part is currently working just fine)
2. Somehow "debtor_contact_id" is read from the payload
3. that value is added as part of a server query to find a separate API
4. the resulting contact info will be pulled into a "contact" model
5. hopefully a hasMany/belongsTo relationship can be established after both corresponding models are returned.
6. all this needs to be done in one promise before entering my template

You will also find the question at: [discuss.emberjs.com](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/establish-a-hasmany-relationship-using-a-foreign-key/6012) if that is more appropriate place to discuss.

I can elaborate more if this does not make sense... thanks!

Comment: I don't see why #6 is so important. You can probably delay rendering (as that seems to be the important bit for you) through an `{{#if}}` until the data is populated for both. I'd stick to delayed rendering, get the belongsTo working and that should do the trick. Also, I just found this article which can probably help with the problem: http://www.toptal.com/emberjs/a-thorough-guide-to-ember-data#.

Comment: I suppose #6 is not a requirement per se... but again, I need to reiterate, I am not using Ember-Data.  I will read this article and re-evaluate if necessary, but I need the flexibility of Ember-Model to work with API of various formats.

Comment: Doh, right ... didn't spot that. What about the documentation at https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model ? `post: Ember.belongsTo('App.Post', {key: 'post_id'})` ... and if it doesn't work, provide actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using ember-data, alongside the attributes of your model you need to add:

```
debtor_contact: DS.belongsTo('name_of_the_other_model')
```

This then provides you a promise which will resolve to the other model on demand. It won't resolve straight away, but bound variables in templates will update as it is resolved. The other API call will be made for you if things are set up properly.

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.html#method_belongsTo

The answer I gave here might also be helpful if you need to force resolving the relationship for some reason: [Ember Unbound & Belongsto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051833/ember-unbound-belongsto/25058312#25058312)

Comment: I am using Ember-Model and adding the belongsTo does not make an additional call to the server.